# Is there a python edge software update tool?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, continuous-integration, device, cd

So I have a simple app written in python and running on a set (10) Raspberry Pis.

- It is a folder with one runnable script.
- I want to have on my external server with public IP some kind of CI/CD like service that would deploy updates to all edge nodes and restart my app on them.
- Internet is rare on edge devices thus I want to push updates when I push some button on the server

Is there such thing for python programs that are meant to run on edge devices?

Comment: just do `import os`, and then `os.system("sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade")`

Comment: this will work on ubuntu and raspberry pi os and debian

Comment: Maybe something like https://github.com/kubeedge/examples ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the main problem is to update and run some script on multiple Raspberry Pi boards, correct?

There are a lot of ready-made solution like [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku) or [piku](https://github.com/piku/piku). Both allows you to do git push deployments to your own servers (manually).

Or you can develop your own solution, using [GitHub webhooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) or some HTML form (for manual push) and Flask web-server that will do CI/CD steps internally.

You'll need to run script like above on each node/board. And configure Webhook with URL similar to: `http://your-domain-or-IP.com:8000/deploy-webhook` but with different port per node.

Or you can open that page manually from browser. Or create separate page that allows you to do that asynchronously. As you'll wish.

```py
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)
script_proc = None
src_path = '~/project/src/'


def bash(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)


def pull_code(path):
    bash('git -C {path} reset --hard'.format(path=path))
    bash('git -C {path} clean -df'.format(path=path))
    bash('git -C {path} pull -f'.format(path=path))
    # or
    # If need just to copy files to remote machine:
    # (example of remote path "pi@192.168.1.1:~/project/src/")
    bash('scp -r {src_path} {dst_path}'.format(src_path=src_path, dst_path=path)) 
    


def installation(python_path):
    bash('{python_path} -m pip install -r requirements.txt'.format(python_path=python_path))


def stop_script():
    global script_proc

    if script_proc:
        script_proc.terminate()


def start_script(python_path, script_path, args=None):
    global script_proc

    script_proc = subprocess.Popen(
        '{} {} {}'.format(str(python_path), script_path, ' '.join(args) or '')
    )


@app.route('/deploy-webhook')
def deploy_webhook():
    project_path = '~/project/some_project_path'
    script_path = 'script1.py'
    python_path = 'venv/bin/python'

    pull_code(project_path)
    installation(python_path)

    stop_script()
    start_script(python_path, script_path)
    return 'Deployed'
```

Comment: @DuckQueen is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The thing is if possible not to use git as a source of content - have a simple on-system folder and a button\script to execute...

Comment: Yes, it is possible, just change operations to copy source code instead. Use of editable version can be difficult to maintain. But still can be ok for you.

Comment: @DuckQueen, any remaining questions?

Answer (score 1):

If your don't need a user interface and use linux I want suggest to use a bash script.
I wrote a simple bash script "to push an update and restart" to
as set for raspberry pi's. Please configure before ssh [with key-less login](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/passwordless.md).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

listOfIps=( 
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.102
192.168.1.103
)

username="pi" 
destDir="work/"
pythonScriptName="fooScript.py"

for i in "${listOfIps[@]}" 
do
     echo "will copy folder \"$1\" with content to ip: ${i} and perform"
     echo "scp -r $1 ${username}@${i}:${destDir}"
     scp -r $1 ${username}@${i}:${destDir}
     echo "will kill all python scripts unfriendly"  
     ssh ${username}@${i} "pkill python" 
     echo "will restart my python scripts ${pythonScriptName} in dir ${destDir} "  
     ssh ${username}@${i} "python3 ${destDir}/${pythonScriptName} &"
done
exit 0
```

save the code in file copyToAll.sh  edit username destDir and your script name  and make it executable:

```
chmod 755 copyToAll.sh
```

call

```
copyToAll.sh myFileToSend
```

Comment: But the main question remains unanswered here: how to restart apps and push that as update to devices.

Comment: okay, but the "update "is done by the copy file process to your pi's, i'snt it ? and a simple restart could be: pkill myPythonScriptsName (kill the process which is called myPythonScriptsName) and python3 myPythonScriptsName.py

Comment: but the main problem is that you need to do that manually on each machine separately. And the author wants to have automatic CI/CD :)

Comment: ok no CI/CD but i added some unfriendly restart commands